# why i am getting error in using replace function in apache pig?

Tags: replace, apache-pig, patch

I am running following command

```
TestData = FOREACH records Generate From as from, MsgId as Msg, REPLACE(toAddress,';' , ',');
```

I am getting following error

> mismatched character
>   '' expecting ''' 2014-04-14 12:27:56,863 [main] ERROR
>   org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200:   mismatched character ''
>   expecting '''

May be it is because of ; character ? if it so then how to apply the patch for it ..

Comment: AFAIK this bug has already been fixed in Pig. Which version do you use?

Comment: I using Apache Pig version 0.11.0-cdh4.3.0 (rexported) from cloudera this is my QA cluster. I have production cluster on which replace is 
working  ...i.e Apache Pig version 0.11.0-cdh4.6.0 (rexported).
And can you please help me to solve this because my QA cluster is down because of this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that Pig `0.11.0-cdh4.3.0` doesn't include [PIG-2507](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-2507).

You either need to patch and rebuild Pig to make it work (Download the patch from here: [https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12571848/PIG_2507.patch](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12571848/PIG%5f2507.patch)) or as a workaround you can create a *custom UDF* based on `org.apache.pig.builtin.REPLACE` :

E.g:

```
package com.example;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;
import org.apache.pig.FuncSpec;
import org.apache.pig.PigWarning;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;
import org.apache.pig.data.DataType;
import org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.schema.Schema;
import org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException;

public class MyReplace extends EvalFunc<String> {

    private String searchString;
    public MyReplace(String searchString) {
        this.searchString = searchString;
    }

    @Override
    public String exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        if (input == null || input.size() < 2)
            return null;

        try {
            String source = (String) input.get(0);
            String replacewith = (String) input.get(1);
            return source.replaceAll(searchString, replacewith);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            warn("Failed to process input; error - " + e.getMessage(), PigWarning.UDF_WARNING_1);
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Schema outputSchema(Schema input) {
        return new Schema(new Schema.FieldSchema(null, DataType.CHARARRAY));
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.apache.pig.EvalFunc#getArgToFuncMapping()
     */
    @Override
    public List<FuncSpec> getArgToFuncMapping() throws FrontendException {
        List<FuncSpec> funcList = new ArrayList<FuncSpec>();
        Schema s = new Schema();
        s.add(new Schema.FieldSchema(null, DataType.CHARARRAY));
        s.add(new Schema.FieldSchema(null, DataType.CHARARRAY));
        funcList.add(new FuncSpec(this.getClass().getName(), s));
        return funcList;
    }
}
```

Pack it in a jar then you can use it:

```
register '/path/to/my.jar';
DEFINE myReplace com.example.MyReplace(';');
A = load 'data' as (a:chararray);
B = FOREACH A generate myReplace(a,',');
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much...your answer is helpful. :) :)

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved by using **Pig** built in function as well.
Instead of special chars in replace function call, use Unicode escape sequences. 
For problem mentioned above use:

```
REPLACE (toAddress,'\\\\u003b','\u002c')
```

in place of:

```
REPLACE(toAddress,';' , ',')
```